# Handle multipart/form-data with arrays in Quarkus

Tags: multipartform-data, quarkus, resteasy, multipart

I generate through an openapi.yaml with quarkus openapi generator the following multipart POST operation, where properties is an array:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/document")
    @Consumes({"multipart/form-data"})
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    @GeneratedMethod ("addDocument")
    public javax.ws.rs.core.Response addDocument(
        @javax.ws.rs.BeanParam AddDocumentMultipartForm multipartForm
    );

    public static class AddDocumentMultipartForm {
        @FormParam("fileContent")
        @org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.PartFilename("fileContentFile")
        @org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        public FileUpload fileContent;
        @FormParam("properties")
        @org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public java.util.List<Long> properties;
    }
```

This works well with this kind of request:

```
    [
        {
            "name": "properties",
            "value": 127
        },
        {
            "name": "properties",
            "value": 128
        },
        {
            "name": "fileContent",
            "type": "application\/pdf",
            "filename": "sample.pdf"
        }
    ]
```

Where I receive an array in properties attribute, but I need to support the following multipart request:

```
[
    {
        "name": "properties[0]",
        "value": 127
    },
    {
        "name": "properties[1]",
        "value": 128
    },
    {
        "name": "fileContent",
        "type": "application\/pdf",
        "filename": "sample.pdf"
    }
]
```

Is it possible to achieve this with quarkus openapi generator?